# How to show a dynamic image URL with Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm kindly asking for help with displaying a dynamic image URL within a Twig template like this:

```
// non-working pseudocode, myImageFilename contains image filename
{% image '@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/' + myImageFilename %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endimage %}
```

but Twig only allows static filename, like this (taken from documentation). I've tried the concatinator `~` like

```
{% image '@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/' ~ myImageFilename %}
```

but it also doesn't work,

```
{% image '@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/example.jpg' %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example"/>
{% endimage %}
```

**Is there a possiblity to use dynamic image URLs with this Twig image logic ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For now, I don't think it is possible do it. The reason behind this is that Assetic is run upfront to dump the asset.

It is possible through this way :

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/appbundle/Resources/public/images/'~myImageFilename }}" alt="Example"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot acceed bundle directory from browser client (.htaccess deny from all), you have to load your image from ./web/ directory instead